# Including Package In Fragment Widget .XML

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I'm adding a fragment called ZipInputFragment within the XML file of one of my activity's.

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/zipCodeFragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.markf.application.ZipInputFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_zip_input" />
```

This runs fine. The issue is that I have a separate package called non_activity where all of my fragments are stored. So when I place the ZipInputFragment in this package, my application crashes. I know that it's because of this line of code in my widget:

```
class="com.markf.application.ZipInputFragment"
```

The issue is that it's not acknowledging the fact that my Fragment is now in a separate package. Does anyone the syntax that would include my non_activity package in the widget? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just use this instead then:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/zipCodeFragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.markf.application.non_activity.ZipInputFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_zip_input" />
```

You just need to add the fully qualified package name to get it to work.

Comment: That still gives me a syntax error. But this worked actually class="non_activity.ZipInputFragment"

Comment: @MarkF what is the package structure which leads to this Fragment? i.e `com.markf.application.etc` cause it looks like you must not have it in the `com.markf` package at all then

Comment: Exactly what you wrote above, com.markf.application.non_activity.ZipInputFragment, so it seemed weird that it wasnt working. But just the package name and Class did the trick. Thanks for the help